# Is there a way to detach a project from CVS in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, version-control, cvs

XCode's CVS support is abysmally bad. Or maybe it's just the server in my organization. Either way, it's leading to more headaches than it's worth so I'd like to "detatch" the project as I can in Eclipse. Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to manually delete all of the CVS files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices.

Double click on your project in the main source list to bring up the "Project "myProject" Info" window.  Make sure the "General" tab is selected.  At the bottom of that tab select "None" from the "SCM Repository" popup menu and close the window.

Or, go to Xcode Preferences window and select the "SCM" tool, select the repository you want to remove, and then remove the repository using the "-" button in the lower left hand corner of the dialog box.  This option is a bit more drastic.

These should both leave all of the invisible CVS directories alone.  This will allow you to manage the repository from the command line and completely hide the CVS info from Xcode.

Good Luck.

Comment: From your experience, is CVS in XCode as bad as I'm making it out to be or would you guess it's some kind of weirdness in my org's network (there is a lot of weirdness here).

Comment: I don't have experience with CVS.  My experience is primarily in Perforce and I've been using git for my personal projects at home.

I use P4V for perforce and the command line for git.

My guess would be that the CVS support in Xcode really is awful.  The Perforce support certainly is.  Every time a file is saved or some other event occurs in Xcode, it verifies everything in my p4 client (100,000+ files)!  All it used to verify, in Xcode 2.5, were the files in my current project (less than 100).  That was fast enough, but with the current implementation it's way too slow.